# Routing Rails Admin Controller Create Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, admin

A dedicated admin/countries_controller is being correctly used for all actions (index, ...), except for creating records. Here the regular countries_controller from the parent controller directory is active:

```
Started POST "/countries" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-06-29 23:26:38 +0200
  Processing by CountriesController#create as HTML
```

What is missing to have the POST action being routed to *admin/countries*?

*routes.rb:*

```
  resources :countries

  namespace :admin do
    resources :countries
  end
```

*rake routes:*

```
     countries GET    /countries(.:format)                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"countries"}
               POST   /countries(.:format)                {:action=>"create", :controller=>"countries"}
   new_country GET    /countries/new(.:format)            {:action=>"new", :controller=>"countries"}

   admin_countries GET    /admin/countries(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/countries"}
                   POST   /admin/countries(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/countries"}
 new_admin_country GET    /admin/countries/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/countries"}
```

Similar question unanswered here:
[Rails help with building Admin area - Routing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181841/rails-help-with-building-admin-area-routing-problem)

Comment: How are you constructing the url, in your view, that initiates the POST request?

Comment: `<%= link_to 'New Country', new_admin_country_path %>` leads to standard scaffold form helper, containing `<%= form_for(@country) do |f| %>` and `<%= f.submit %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `form_for` needs to be namespaced too:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @country] do |f| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

When you pass `@country` to `form_for` it's not going to know what namespace you want this form to go to and so it will default to just the standard `POST /countries` URL.